# MySQL: Get distinct values of column row order by date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I'm trying to get a set of results that are sorted by descending date and where the value of a column (zone_id) is not repeated, but I can't find the right query.

The column I am really interested in is the 2nd column (zone_id) but I have shown the id column in order to make it clearer the result I want to obtain.

The table simply sorted by date has the following data:

| id | zone_id | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 206 | 63 | 2021-05-11 09:22:19 |
| 205 | 63 | 2021-05-11 09:21:53 |
| 204 | 22 | 2021-05-11 09:21:38 |
| 5 | 33 | 2021-05-10 10:45:09 |
| 6 | 23 | 2021-05-10 10:45:09 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-05-10 10:45:02 |
| 137 | 63 | 2021-03-06 17:02:25 |
| 143 | 67 | 2021-03-03 20:24:14 |
| 98 | 14 | 2020-11-06 14:49:44 |
| 177 | 29 | 2020-08-16 20:09:26 |

So that, in this case the values it should receive should be:

> 63, 22, 33, 23, 3, 67, 14, 29

I have tried the following queries without success:

```
SELECT zone_id, id, updated_at 
FROM table 
GROUP BY zone_id 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

> shows: 23, 33, 3, 67, 84, 63, 88, 98,...

```
SELECT DISTINCT zone_id, id, updated_at 
FROM table 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

> shows: 63, 63, 22, 33, 23, 3, 63, 67,...

Please, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance:

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you want `row_number()` to choose one row per zone and then ordering:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by zone_id order by updated_at desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by updated_at desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below -

```
SELECT ZONE_ID FROM
(
SELECT zone_id, updated_at 
FROM table 
GROUP BY zone_id 
) T
ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

Comment: This query does not get the desired result. Thanks anyway,